# broken link in symfony using assetic and angular

Tags: php, css, symfony, fonts, assetic

I have bundle and in the resources folder I have assets folder with bower component folder (not using bower or grunt only assetic) ,
so one of the bower component is ui-grid and I have few error 404.
The internal links  that called from inside the "ui-grid.min.js" to dist folder or other relative folder  became with the following pattern , for exmaple:
http://domain.com/Resources/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
and off course it is throw 404 error in the console.

how can I fix it,  it is relevant to fonts and icon

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar situation before and I just needed to change the url path to the glyphicons within the CSS file (or SASS/LESS files if you are using those). I believe there were around 4-5 that needed changing.